# combine same values of master array with slave array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one master array and multi slave arrays and i need function that replace values on same array keys.

**example:**

master array:

```
$master = array(**"a"=>"master a"**,**"b"=>"master b"** "c"=>"master c");
```

slave arrays:

```
$slave_a = array("s1"=>array(**"a"=>"slave a"**,"f"=>"slave f"));
$slave_b = array("s2"=>"slave" **"b"="slave b"**);
```

I need function to filter slave arrays to look like:

```
$slave_a to be array("s1"=>array(**"a"=>"master a"**,"f"=>"slave f"));
$slave_b to be array("s2"=>"slave" **"b"="master b"**);
```

Тhanks in advance and sorry for my poor English

Comment: How many sub-arrays could be within the slave multiarrays? Will it always be like [ [] [] [] [] ] or could it go this way also: [ [ [ [ [] [] ] [] [] ] ] [] [] ] ? (Hope You understand the [] notation).

Comment: ok...  the $master array and slave arrays are content from **parse_ini_file** function. The master array is without process sections but the slave aray have cases with process sections "true". 
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this gave me not very clear answer to my question. In Your ini file You can have sections that will create multilevel arrays or only a matrix of arrays. So? Please paste the example of the ini file in Your question.

Comment: multi level arrays and single level array are slaves. Slave array are basic configurations for my php scripts but i need to correct it with one, one level master array.

Comment: first ini content (slave)
`
[MAIN]
lib=lib_folder;
bin=bin_folder;
usr=usr_folder;
etc=etc_folder;
class;
`
second ini content (slave)

`
alib=1;
abin=0;
ausr_other=usr/tree;
`

master ini:

`
lib=lib_other;
abin=1;

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after parsing the ini files using `parse_ini_file` You should end up with arrays similar to this (when using process sections TRUE):

```
$first_ini = array(
    'MAIN' => array(
        'lib' => 'lib_folder',
        'bin' => 'bin_folder',
        'usr' => 'usr_folder',
        'etc' => 'etc_folder'
    )
);

$second_ini = array(
    'alib' => 1,
    'abin' => 0,
    'ausr_other' => 'usr/tree'
);

$master_ini = array(
    'lib' => 'lib_other',
    'abin' => 1
);
```

Then You can use this simple function (not tested):

```
function combine_master_with_slave($master, $slave) {
    foreach($slave as $key => $val) { // we will loop through slave array
        if(is_array($val)) { // if the value is an array use recursion
            $slave[$key] = combine_master_with_slave($master, $val);
        }
        if(isset($master[$key])) { // if master array contains the same key as a slave array, replace it's value by the master's one
            $slave[$key] = $master[$key];
        }
    }
    return $slave; // finaly return the processed slave array
}
```

But I am really not sure whether this will work, maybe it will need some slight modifications...

Also You will have to call this function so many times as many slave arrays You have, or in other words, You will have to call this function for each slave array.

This should work for any sub-array level, even it would be [ [ [ [ [ [][][][] ] ] ] ] ].